# SPSS, analysis of variables representing events of different types

Tags: spss

i'm new to SPSS and this is probably just a matter of pointing me to the right keyword.

I have the following kind of data:

```
Person  Event1  Event2  Event3  Event4
---------------------------------------
1      ¦  2    ¦  1    ¦  23   ¦  -66
2      ¦  12   ¦  3    ¦  11   ¦  -99
3      ¦  4    ¦  4    ¦  -99  ¦  -99
```

Every person has 0-4 events that happend. Those events where of a certain type, lets say there are 25 types and an additional 2 invalid types, -99 for no event happend, and -66 for missing information (event may have happend, but the data is missing).

I found out that this are probably not multiple choice variables, as the same type of event can happen multiple times to the same person. So i'm a little bit lost about the specific keywords to use in my google searches.

What i want do do is for example say, if a patient has often an event of type 3, type 11 also happens. Or on average they have 2 events (of any type).

Thank you for any help to point me in the right direction, if you are unsure on how to do it and you just think you know the right keyword i can search for, i would be glad to hear that as well!

Comment: For the relationship between types I would suggest looking at `CROSSTABS` of the tables. For they have 2 events of any type, you would need to create a new column counting the valid number of types and then look at the `MEANS` or maybe other `CROSSTABS`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new here. If I were you, I would program the syntax.
For your first questoin on events 3 and 11 happening together:

```
DO IF (Event2 = 3 & Event3 = 11).
COMPUTE NewVariable3Plus11 = 1.
ELSE.
COMPUTE NewVariable3Plus11 = 0.
END IF.
```

In this case you create a variable "NewVariable3Plus11" which is equl to 1 if both cases appear or to 0 if not. You have to make it more complicated to compare all Event variables and not only Event2 and Event3.

For your second question on tow events of any type:

```
DO IF (Event1 => 0 & Event2 => 0 | Event3 => 0 | Event4 => 0).
COMPUTE NewVariableTwoEvents = 1.
ELSE IF (Event2 => 0 & Event3 => 0 | Event4 => 0).
COMPUTE NewVariableTwoEvents = 1.
ELSE IF (Event3 => 0 & Event4 => 0).
COMPUTE NewVariableTwoEvents = 1.
ELSE.
COMPUTE NewVariableTwoEvents = 0.
END IF.
```

If I am correct, SPSS will go throug your cases and if there were two events (-66 and -99 are less than 0), it will create a variable "NewVariableTwoEvents" equal to 1. Otherwise - 0.

Best,
Eugene
PS. I did not test it, but this could be one of possible approaches.

Comment: thank you :) but i keep wondering why i souldnt just do that with excel. But i will look into it, might teach me other new things :)

Comment: You can do the same vriable calculation in Excel, it is very similar. But when you perform further statistic operations, SPSS is obviously better!